# Django ListView works but DetailView not displaying Model Data

Tags: django, listview, templates

I am helping my daughter with her computing Project for school. It is a simple generic forum type application.

She has a **ListView** for a model which **works fine**:

```
{% extends 'users/main.html' %}

    <!-- Here is where our content will begin -->
    {% block content %}
      <h1>This is posts.html!</h1>
      <br/>

      {% for obj in object_list %}
          <h2>{{ obj.topic }}</h2>
          {{ obj.date_posted }}
          <br/>
          {{ obj.content }}
          <br/>
          Author: {{ obj.author }}
          <br/><br/>
      {% endfor %}

    {% endblock %}
```

She then added a **DetailView** which is simply the same code with the loop removed:

```
{% extends 'users/main.html' %}

    <!-- Here is where our content will begin -->
    {% block content %}

      <h1>This is posts.html!</h1>
      <br/>
      {{ obj.id }}
      <h2>{{ obj.topic }}</h2>
      {{ obj.date_posted }}
      <br/>
      {{ obj.content }}
      <br/>
      Author: {{ obj.author }}
      <br/><br/>

    {% endblock %}
```

This is then called with a '....post/1/' (post id = 1 does exist (checked via DB Browser and in the ListView) and the path and naming of the template is correct.
Frustratingly, this displays the page but not the details inside the django temp language brackets (object.topic etc)!

When I look at the page source for the section dealing with the detail, I get:

[screenshot of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbyjO.png)

and the source code looks like so:

```
  <h1>This is posts.html!</h1>
  <br/>

  

  <h2></h2>
  
  <br/>
  
  <br/>
  Author: 

  <br/><br/
```

It is simply ignoring the bracketed templating code - any ideas?

Comment: why do you think object name in template should be obj, where does this idea come form

Comment: Thanks, I accept that that was wrong - I changed it but it is still not working

Comment: what did you change it to, did you consult documentation?

Comment: i changed it to {{ object.id }} etc as suggested by Nebojsa in another reply

Comment: Show us your DetailVeiw

Comment: @Curmudgeon Along with the DetailView also add your urlpatterns to the question. (Plus specify the exact name of your template)

Answer (score 0):

Django DetailView returns 'object' inside context by default.

If you did not change 'context_object_name' variable, then use {{object}} instead of {{obj}}

```
<h1>This is posts.html!</h1>
  <br/>
  {{ object.id }}
  <h2>{{ object.topic }}</h2>
  {{ object.date_posted }}
  <br/>
  {{ object.content }}
  <br/>
  Author: {{ object.author }}
  <br/><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I tried that but sadly, it still doesn't work.

It still isn't seeing everything in curly brackets:

Comment: Can you send screenshot of detail view please?

Add context object name for example:

class Example(DetailView):
   model = SomeModel
   template_name = 'some_template.html'
   context_object_name = 'something'

Then you will be able to call object with that name (in this case {{something}} )

Comment: Here is a link to the screenshot - sorry for inefficiency , I am new to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdvar.png

Comment: It has to return object, just add context_object_name = 'forum' after Model instance and then call {{forum.topic}}, {{forum.date_posted}} etc

Answer (score 0):

Really thanks a lot for all of this.

I corrected my template to include 'object' and made it march all conventions to avoid having to send in context information.

It still wouldn't work.

I rebooted localhost repeatedly because it all made no sense.

Finally, I rebooted my daughters PC and immediately, everything worked.

A lesson learned and as a dad helping a 17 year old daughter who did his Computer Science degree 40(!) years ago, another lesson in how complicated and challenging understanding a framework can be.

I must say - it has been fun.

Thanks again,

Howard.